# UITableView edit mode prevents cells deallocating and slow down dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

My app shows a screen with `UITableView` several times. With each time more showing it starts slow down in presenting cells (`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` spends more and more time). With debugging and experimenting I found a problem place. When I set `self.tableView.editing = YES` my custom cells stop receiving *dealloc* message when controller is being deallocated. It blows my mind and seems like a bug.

Could anyone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning off `UITableView` edit mode in controller `dealloc` method solves this problem and cells memory are deallocated as usual.

```
-(void)dealloc {
    self.tableView.editing = NO;
}
```